# Why is the list.copy() method shallow?

Tags: python, list, copy, deep-copy, shallow-copy

In the official Python documentation said that list.copy() returns a shallow copy of the list.
But according to the following code it is deep copy since the change of one list does not lead to the change in another.

```
>>> num1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> num2 = num1.copy()
>>> num1.append(9)
>>> num1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
>>> num2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What is the problem? Where is a mistake?

Comment: That's what a shallow copy is. You're confusing a shallow copy with not-being-a-copy.

Comment: The copy is shallow because if `num1` contained lists or dictionaries, those structures would not be copied.

Comment: If copy() did what you are thinking, why would it be a necessary function?  Wouldn't `num2 = num1` then do the same thing?

Comment: There is no difference between shallow and deep when the list elements are numbers; there is nothing "below" the numbers.

Comment: Can anyone give a link on resource where it explained in details?

Comment: @molbdnilo well, in this case, it doesn't matter what the elements are, the behavior would be the same

Comment: I still do not understand the difference. Can anyone give link on literature or video with detailed explanation?

Answer (score 2):

This example will demonstrate why this is a shallow copy

```
>>> num1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> num2 = num1.copy()
>>> num1[0].append(9)
>>> num1
[[1, 2, 3, 9], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> num2
[[1, 2, 3, 9], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Since the original list contained mutable elements, the outer copy contains *shallow* copies to the mutable elements.

Comment: But why it does not work with simple list? I do not understand. Why in case of simple list it does not effect the copied one

Comment: @NikaMazulina Because it's a copy.

Comment: But in case of nested list for example it effects the copy. It is also just a copy. What is the difference?

Comment: @NikaMazulina because `num1[0].append(9)` isn't changing the list, it is changing an *element inside the list*.