# In python, why is appending a list to a larger list, then updating one of them, also updating all the other appended lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to update a list of Recorded Coordinates for a simple snake game. However, when I try to save the coordinates in the list, they all update to the most recent values.

I have tried setting the coordinates to a more global scale instead of inside a class file and making copies of the data I need, however none of these worked. A simple example of this is here:

```
my_list = []
run = True
var1 = [5, 50]
i = 0
while run and i <= 10:
    i += 1
    my_list.append(var1)
    var1[0] += 1
    var1[1] -= 1
print(my_list)
```

I am running python 3.11.0.

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that each time you append `var1` to `my_list`, you append a reference to the same object. If you subsequently change data in that object (i.e. by `var1[0] += 1`), then that has an effect on all elements of `my_list`. That's just how Python deals with lists. You can read more on that in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022296/how-memory-address-of-list-in-python-work) or you check out general Python documentation on lists.

A solution in your case could be to make a copy of the list `var1` in each iteration, and append that copy to `my_list`. In that case, all elements of `my_list` will point to a different location in memory. This is achieved by simply calling `.copy()` on the list at hand:

```
my_list = []
run = True
var1 = [5, 50]
i = 0
while run and i <= 10:
    i += 1
    my_list.append(var1.copy())
    var1[0] += 1
    var1[1] -= 1
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Note that this `.copy` works as long as var1 does not contain lists or dicts or other mutable elements, in which case you need a deepcopy. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64104416/2745495